# I accidentally ran `rm -rf /*` on my wsl, what should i do

Tags: data-recovery, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, rm

I accidentally ran `rm -rf /*` on my wsl **(with root permission)**. *and i* rebooted and it became unusable. What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I just ran rm /\* accidentally, any fix?](https://superuser.com/questions/553973/i-just-ran-rm-accidentally-any-fix)

Comment: @Tetsujin Just a heads up the the answer is a bit worse that that, since this not only destroys the Linux filesystem, but also Windows, so I don't quite consider the WSL version of this question a duplicate

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds - Ouch! I was aware it was basically a case of "How good is your backup?" but hadn't considered the double whammy of it being linux *inside* Windows, with full perms.

Comment: You rebooted what? Your host system or the WSL system? Both? Something else?

Answer (score 4):

I can only offer condolences and hope you have a backup of important files.  Because, by default, WSL mounts your Windows drives in each WSL distribution (`/mnt/c`, etc.), a recursive `rm` from the root of the WSL virtual drive *will* extend into the Windows mounted filesystem. The integration between WSL and Windows is much tighter than a traditional "VM", and the resulting damage from this mistake is much more catastrophic.

It honestly doesn't matter (much) if you run the command as root or as the regular WSL user, since it's your *regular* WSL user that has access to your *Windows* user's files.  It would be the same as running a recursive `remove-item` from PowerShell as your regular Windows user.

While Windows system files won't be deleted (unless you were running WSL as a *Windows* administrator), your Windows *user* files were removed (likely including all application settings, desktop, etc.), so you will almost certainly not be able to log in to Windows after rebooting.

You aren't the first person to do this, so see [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1354571/1165986) for other advice I've given when this has happened in the past. Ultimately, you are almost certainly looking at a full reinstall and (hopefully) restore from backup.